# Check if data exists in firebase using Ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if a certain value exists in my firebase real time database. However, it keeps saying that it does not exist.
This is my code

```
check(){
       var checkRef = firebase.database().ref('users');

       checkRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('referralCode')) {
          console.log("Referral Code exist.");
        }
        else {
          console.log("Referral Code does not exist.");
        }
     });
 
 
 }
```

Thanks

I am using Ionic 5

Comment: Please edit the question to show your database structure.  It's not clear what your hoping to check with the snapshot that you received.  It's very likely that you're simply looking at the wrong data within the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using javascript "hasOwnProperty" method while you need to use firebase provided method ["hasChild"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#haschild):

```
// Assume we have the following data in the Database:
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace"
  }
}

// Determine which child keys in DataSnapshot have data.
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var hasName = snapshot.hasChild("name"); // true
    var hasAge = snapshot.hasChild("age"); // false
  });
```

So in your case should be something like:

```
check(){
       var checkRef = firebase.database().ref('users');

       checkRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasChild('referralCode')) {
          console.log("Referral Code exist.");
        }
        else {
          console.log("Referral Code does not exist.");
        }
     });
 
 }
```